# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: armv7

my app got one error.  Xcode ios5 gm_seed .
i have add libz1.2.5.dynlib to OTHER_LDFlag

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___zzip_aligned4", referenced from:
      ___zzip_parse_root_directory in libZZipLib.a(zip.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I finally fixed a similar error with Cocos2D was to search for the function in question. In your case, `ctrl+shift+f` for `zzip_aligned4`, then `alt+click` on the function name to go to the definition. You may find that rather than libz.2.5, it's in standard libz or another version of libz.