# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 on Xcode 4.6.3 for iPhone5

Tags: ios, xcode

I got the error like this:

Xcode version: 4.6.3
target: iphone 5

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OFFlickrAPIContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OFFlickrAPIRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in SharingViewController.o
  "_OFFlickrWritePermission", referenced from:
      -[SharingViewController flickrAPIRequest:didObtainOAuthRequestToken:secret:] in SharingViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The objective flickr library is generated.

Comment: There are so many questions similar to this. Some of them: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765163/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Flicker Library is not supporting currently architecture so You have to update that Library.Try this one solution..Your Problem might get solved